# Unable to get newly created Logins from Remote SQL Server Instance using SMO & C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

```
//Check if Login ID exist in SQL Server
var svr = new Server(InstanceName); // CONSTANT
var login = new Login(svr, LoginName); // CONSTANT

//If Login doesn't already exist
if (svr.Logins.Contains(LoginName)) // Unable to find newly created Login here
{
    //Login should be of type Sql Login
    login.LoginType = Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.LoginType.SqlLogin;
    login.PasswordPolicyEnforced = false;

    //Create the Login on the SQL Server with password: pa$$w0rd              
    login.ChangePassword(txtBoxNewPassword.Text.Trim());
    return;
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code or is it a summary? I ask because I've seen the behavior that you're describing if, say, I create the server object, get the LoginCollection (from `svr.Logins`), and then a new login is created outside of my program. The fix is simple enough: call `svr.Logins.Refresh()`.

If this is your actual code, what do you mean by "newly created logins"? That is, what are the steps to reproduce your problem?

Comment: This is a actual code. What I want is to change the password for a login from remote instance but when I apply the code I can only see 'sa' and 'BUILTIN\Users' and no other users. I created the login using SSMS then I run the code but can not see the newly created login. Also, note that when I apply the same code to my local sql server instance I am able to see all the logins

Comment: Then that sounds like either a permissions problem with whatever account you're using to connect to the SQL Server with out your connecting to the wrong server. It could still be the first problem i mentioned though if you program is already running when you add the login through SSMS.